# drupal behat test assert authenticated by role with given fields

Tags: 7, testing

I am trying to run the following behat step:

```
@Given I am logged in as a user with the :role role(s) and I have the following fields:
```

This is defined in DrupalContext.php on lines 68-106.  I have a standard behat install from composer.  When I run this, I get the following error:

> --- FeatureContext has missing steps. Define them with these snippets:
>
> /**
>        * @Given I am logged in as a user with the :arg1 and I have the following fields:
>        */
>       public function iAmLoggedInAsAUserWithTheAndIHaveTheFollowingFields($arg1, TableNode $table)
>       {
>           throw new PendingException();
>       }

I am still pretty new to OOPHP so when I read this I took it to mean that it couldn't find the original method.  I added a use statement in my feature/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php:

```
use Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\assertAuthenticatedByRole;
```

But I still get the same results.  Here is my implementation of the behat scenario:

```
@api
Scenario: An administrator should not be able to create a page content
  Given I am logged in as a user with the 'administrator' and I have the 
  following fields:
    | field_user_username     | drupaltest  |
```

Comment: Sounds like your test class is missing the method your definition claims will be available: `iAmLoggedInAsAUserWithTheAndIHaveTheFollowingFields()`

Comment: Could it also be missing `role(s)` text after `administrator`?

Comment: @Kevin ding ding ding. We have a winner.

Comment: Adding as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your Given condition - you need to have `role(s)` after administrator.

```
Given I am logged in as a user with the 'administrator' role(s) and I have the following fields:
```